# insert data to table based on another table C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, insert, oledb

I wrote some code that takes some values from one table and inserts the other table with these values.(not just these values, but also these values(this values=values from the based on table))

and I get this error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E10): value wan't given for one or more of the required parameters.`

here's the code.  I don't know what i've missed.

```
string selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
Codons cdn = new Codons(selectedItem);
string codon1;
int index;

if (this.i != this.counter)
{
  //take from the DataBase the matching codonsCodon1 to codonsFullName
  codon1 = cdn.GetCodon1();

  //take the serialnumber of the last protein
  string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
         "Data Source=C:\\Projects_2012\\Project_Noam\\Access\\myProject.accdb";
  OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
  conn.Open();
  string last= "SELECT proInfoSerialNum FROM tblProInfo WHERE proInfoScienceName = "+this.name ;
  OleDbCommand getSerial = new OleDbCommand(last, conn);
  OleDbDataReader dr = getSerial.ExecuteReader();
  dr.Read();
  index = dr.GetInt32(0);

  //add the amino acid to tblOrderAA
  using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
  {
    string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO tblOrderAA(orderAASerialPro, orderAACodon1) "
           + " values (?, ?)";
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(insertCommand, connection))
    {
      connection.Open();
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("orderAASerialPro", index);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("orderAACodon1", codon1);
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:I put a messagebox after that line:

```
index = dr.GetInt32(0);
```

to see where is the problem, and I get the error before that. I don't see the messagebox

Answer (score 1):

Your SELECT Command has a syntax error in it because you didn't enclose it with quotes.

Change this:

```
string last = "SELECT proInfoSerialNum FROM tblProInfo WHERE proInfoScienceName = "+this.name ;
OleDbCommand getSerial = new OleDbCommand(last, conn);
OleDbDataReader dr = getSerial.ExecuteReader();
```

to

```
string last = "SELECT proInfoSerialNum FROM tblProInfo WHERE proInfoScienceName = ?";
OleDbCommand getSerial = new OleDbCommand(last, conn);
getSerial.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", this.name);
OleDbDataReader dr = getSerial.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: @user1017315 I copied your code and that's where the error was.  Which line in the code is actually generating the error?

Comment: the code compiles. but here all the details in the error message System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E10): value wan't given for one or more of the required parameters.
    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling (OleDbHResult hr)
    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult (tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object & executeResult)
    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText (Object & executeResult)
    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand (CommandBehavior behavior, Object & executeResult)

Comment: @user1017315 It still looks like my answer fixes that.  Did you look at how I changed the `string last` statement?

Answer (score 0):

This code is example from [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access):

```
string SqlString = "Insert Into Contacts (FirstName, LastName) Values (?,?)";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
    {
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", txtLastName.Text);
       conn.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Try to do the same as in the example.